# Assign multiline string to variable in script

Tags: ksh, prompt

I want a variable, let’s say `PS`, defined in my `.profile` file with the following value:

```
PS1='PWD: ${PWD}
$ '
```

So that when I enter `$PS` in my terminal, I get a two-lined prompt string, the first line showing my working directory. How can I define this in my `.profile` file?

Edit: the question that this is purportedly a duplicate of is not the same at all. My question is about assigning a multiline value to a variable in a shell script. Neither `\n` nor `\` followed by Enter appear to work. Note that the assignment I wrote works perfectly well interactively. In fact, I have it saved it in my OneNote and often copy/paste it in my shell. But I would like it to be in my `.profile` file or another script so I can skip this step, and writing it as is in a script does not work. Finally, if someone suggests a change where PS1 is changed automatically, that is OK, but the ideal would be if the whole thing above was assigned to a variable like `PS` so that when I typed `$PS`, `PS1` would be set.

Edit 2: I found a solution. In .profile:

```
PS1="PWD: ${PWD}
\$ "
```

This changes PS1 only when I run
`. .profile`
Which is weird because I know `.profile` is being run in some way on startup (I try echoing variables that are defined in `.profile` before running it and they exist; I’m guessing there is some other file that is being run automatically after `.profile` that sets `PS1` to the default one-liner), but I guess it’s what I want because I want some control over whether my change is effective. If I want my change to be effective I run `. .profile`, if not I don’t do anything. Sorry for the confusion, I was trying to experiment and update the description as fast as I could!

Comment: What you have should work.  Although I'm guessing you want `$(pwd)` instead of `${PWD}`

Comment: @jesse_b what I have works interactively, not in a script.

Comment: I can't see why that assignment above with a quoted hard newline shouldn't work in `.profile`. And it appears to work with both ksh and Bash at least on my Mac.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for the poke. I would agree with all that you've said. The assignment should be working with no issues. The variable would be expanded at the time of the assignment, though, which is the issue that the duplicate is dealing with. I see nothing in the question indicating _in what way_ the assignment does not work and when I closed it as a duplicate I presumed that the only issue with it was the fact that the working directory would never update when the user changed it with `cd`.

Comment: Seeing the edits, I think you're chasing the wrong thing. You shouldn't be trying to execute an unquoted variable ("when I enter `$PS`"). Instead, define a function: `PS() { PS1=whatever; }`. Then you can execute the function by running `PS`, and it will update the variable.

Comment: Further, the way the edits changed the code make no sense at all. The first code block using single quotes as seen _now_ is what should work perfectly, but you claim that the second code block with double quotes which suffer from the flaw in the duplicate is what works. (It might appear to workz but you'll see the problem immediately after you change directories.)

Comment: @muru sorry for the confusion, Edit 2 should be accurate now. Later on, I should maybe make a final edit of the question that makes it clear to someone reading it for the first time, but I don’t know the etiquette for editing a question I found the answer to.

Comment: (1) I’m sorry, but the whole “when I enter `$PS` in my terminal” angle doesn’t make any sense to me. (2) You say it “does not work”, but you have declined to explain in what way it fails. (3) And since your solution is the same as what you started with (except for the `\$`), I don’t know what you were ever asking. (4) As soon as you submit your first edit for review, people will start considering your question for reopening. You should not rush this step. Make the best argument you can for why the question should be reopened — it’s OK if you take a few days.

Comment: I don’t need it reopened now that I found a solution.

Comment: Actually it seems like I don’t even need the backslash. All I needed was to run `. .profile`. In any case, there is no sense in which my question is a duplicate of the one purported.

Comment: Actually I do need the backslash. The other question is somewhat useful in that I guessed from it to use backslash, but it’s not a direct answer to my question. If you consider that this is a duplicate of that, it’s fine.

Comment: The backslash at that particular place won't make any difference unless you're root.

Answer (score -1):

To define the PS variable in your .profile file with the specified value, you can simply add the following line:

```
export PS1="PWD: \${PWD}\n\$ "
```

Comment: Why do you export the variable? Do you know for a fact that the `ksh` shell interprets `\n` as a newline when it's part of the `PS1` variable?

Comment: I did this and it does not interpret `\n` correctly. It says `PWD: ` followed by my working directory and then `n$ `, all on one line.

Comment: this works in Bash, but it doesn't appear to work in ksh (at least not the ksh that came with my Mac)